# How to make `C-x 9` the same as `C-x 8 "`

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

For typing german text with an english keyboard layout the binding `C-x 8 "` is very valuable. After typing it I can insert umlauts easily. Here is what which-key shows me after typing `C-x 8 "`

[image: characters are maped to Umlauts]

I use this so often that I would like to use `C-x 9` as an "alias" for this binding.

Unfortunatelly I can't figure out how. `C-x 8 "` is only a partial binding if I see it correctly. `describe-key` `C-x 8 "` doesn't show me anything and just waits for further input. It also doesn't seem to be

Ideally I would like something like

```
(set-global-key-alias-or-so "C-x 9" "C-x 8 \"")
```

or

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 9") 'whatever-is-behind-C-x-8-\")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this.  The main practical difference is whether you see `C-x 8 "` or `C-x 9` in the minibuffer while waiting to read the next key.

Option 1 is to simulate the user actually typing <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 9") #'my-ctl-x-8-double-quote)

(defun my-ctl-x-8-double-quote ()
  "Simulate typing: C-x 8 \""
  (interactive)
  (dolist (event (nreverse (list ?\C-x ?8 ?\")))
    (push (cons t event) unread-command-events)))
```

Option 2 is to bind <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> to the same keymap used by <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> (which is defined in `key-translation-map`):

```el
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-x 9")
  (lookup-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-x 8 \"")))
```

Note that option 2 requires you to figure out where that prefix keymap lives (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> helps with that), while option 1 can be used even if you don't know that information.

See also: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Translation Keymaps`

Comment: Very cool indeed. I went for option 2 which looks much cleaner to me and works flawlessly. Thank you.